# Why use a static char buffer to instantiate a C++ class loaded from a DLL

Tags: c++, dll, new-operator

today I saw this C++ code to istantiate a class which resides in a DLL from an EXE (after loading the DLL)

```
extern "C"
{
    DLL_EXPORT MyClass *CreateClass()
    {
        static char classBuffer[sizeof(MyClass)];

        return new ((void*)classBuffer)MyClass();
    }
}
```

I don't understand why here we don't simply use the new operator and instead we first declare that static buffer and then use it with the class istantiation. Any help is appreciated

Comment: It is a bad code. Don't do that unless you want singleton, even then it is not quite right.

Comment: why is it bad code? And why we couldn't use a static variable of type MyClass instead of char?

Comment: @Nawaz, it's not even a working singleton since every time you call the function, the constructor is called again (and again, and again) on the same memory location. [oops looks like you edited your comment in the meantime]

Comment: This will reinitialize the object at each call. It will also avoid leak detection, as nothing is allocated from the heap. Also, the object is never destroyed. Wonder if any of this is intentional?

Comment: @Stefano using a `static` variable of type `MyClass` and returning a pointer to it would make it behave like a singleton. The code above is just bad because every time the function is called it calls the `MyClass` constructor and uses placement new to initialize the same buffer over and over. But then again, maybe the author intended exactly that. It's impossible to tell without knowing what the use case is.

Comment: @syam: Yes, that is why I said "even then it is not quite right". It also has alignment issues.

Comment: It was probably a hack around a memory management problem.  Returning pointers from a DLL is quite troublesome when the DLL and the client app don't share the same CRT.  Something goes kapooey when the client code tries to release the object with the wrong allocator.  Not that this solves the problem, it just hides it and adds new ones.

Comment: @Praetorian I found the code in the CryEngine 3 SDK source which you can download at crydev.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it avoids dependency on `new` and `delete`, but still calls the constructor.

But it also means that you can't have multiple instances of the class [in the same process, at least]. That may be intentional, to avoid more than one instance, or it may be a flaw. It all depends on what the purpose of the class itself is. But it would be a bad idea to call this function more than once - and I think that it should have some protection against that.

I feel that this is not the ideal way to solve the problem, but without understanding the overall "background" of the class and this implementation, it's hard to say what other solutions there are and which one is the correct one here.